# How do you quickly clear away trees without destroying my creations

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to create a theme park, but I forgot to make my world flat before creating it. I've already built a lot so I don't want to destroy my builds. I've tried the `/replaceitem` command, but it didn't work.

Is there an easy way to get rid of all the trees on my map without destroying my creations?

Comment: what version and platform are you on?

Comment: For your version of BE, I am assuming that it is the latest update, 1.14.60

Answer (score 3):

Increase the `randomTickSpeed` game rule to a high value like `1000` using `/gamerule`. Then break the wood blocks of the trees, and the leaves will begin to deteriorate very quickly.

There is no faster solution without using mods/add-ons/plugins. `/replaceitem` is used for different purposes other than manipulating blocks in your world.

Comment: Given that the leaves will decay very quickly, items like saplings and apples may rain down from the sky, so would we want to add `/kill @e[type=item]`?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

you can use`/fill (corner one) (corner two) air replace oak_log`
this will change all the oak logs into air blocks in the chosen area, you can also do as many have suggested and also use `/gamerule randomtickspeed 100`

I hope this can help you!

Comment: This is bedrock

Comment: The command should still work the same

Comment: No it does mot work. The fill command is different in bedrock. Look it up if u want

Comment: For anyone wondering why this does not work, it is because 1) `oak_log` does not exist, only `log` with data `0`. 2) syntax just isn't correct, a data is a must with the replace mode even if it is `0`

Comment: Thank you. That's usefull to know

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it works (burnt down an ecosystem)

Go into settings to set random tick speed to 4096

Next, get flint and steel (assuming it can't burn down)

Then Go HAM! Spam click everywhere

Hopefully, that helped.

Comment: sorry this was my first awnser

Comment: also 4096 is the max randomtick speed :)

Comment: Yes, and thanks for that info! I thought there was no maximum to `randomTickSpeed`, or if there is one, it would be something like `2147483647`. I'll have to look into that. Thanks!

Comment: on bedrock or PE it is 4096  AKA settings then go to the bottom and type 9999 and it brings you to 4096

Comment: Oh, I see it now. PS. Use the share link under *my* answer post, not the share link under the question post.

Comment: There we go :) I hope that it worked

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Come on, you're making this into too big of a deal. Besides, Locomeon suggested burning down the trees, not breaking the logs of the trees. 

It's like if I accused my friend from copying me because we both used wood to build a house in minecraft, even though the two creations are different.

Comment: Can confirm that this is indeed the most fun method of doing this.

Comment: yes I make worlds devoted to killing all the tree

Comment: @Quijibo But he still suggested changing the gamerule `randomTickSpeed`, which I suggested first. The part about burning the trees instead is very creative and I like that, but because he suggested changing the gamerule, that idea was mine because I got there first. So he should credit me for it.

Comment: @JordanHoughtaling And also, if you liked this answer, please consider clicking the check button to the left so that you know the problem is solved.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 He is simply taking some steps that are the same, clearly not inspired by your answer. Microsoft also doesn't credit Apple for using operational systems on their devices.

Comment: @Quijibo I see, it makes sense now. I can remove the link now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try `/fill [Position_1] [Position2] air 0 replace [type of block you want to replace]` This will fill an area with air but only destroy a single type of block instead of all of them. Then repeat the command twice with logs and leaves